# Typescript doesn't complain about missing imports

Tags: typescript

Contents of foo.ts:

```
let a: Person = new Person();
```

Contents of bar.ts:

```
class Person {}
```

The tsconfig.json file contains the default set of values created by `tsc --init`.

I'm using typescript version 2.6.2.

The code above simply compiles with no errors about `Person` being not defined. If I rename `Person` to `Persons` in foo.ts, then it does throw an error saying `cannot find name 'Persons'`. So it's as if it is automatically importing this file somehow.

Also note that I'm not exporting the `Person` class in bar.ts. If I do add an export statement, then everything behaves as it should - I get an error saying `cannot find name 'Person'`.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Is this a user error?

Edit:

Maybe this makes sense in the browser, but to me this behavior makes no sense in a node.js application. Is there a Typescript flag which forbids this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler flag `--isolatedModules` will ensure that all .ts files are modules. Once you make `foo.ts` and `bar.ts` modules by adding at 1 `import` or `export`, then the `Person` class will not be global anymore.

This, however doesn't solve the following similar issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18232#issuecomment-359200157

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the answer, this one is supposed to be marked as correct!

Answer (score 4):

Your bar.ts is not a module, since it doesn't have any import nor any export. So it defines a global Person class, that doesn't need to be imported, since it's global. Export it, and TypeScript will complain about the missing import.

Comment: But the point is compiling this code is successful, but when you run it, node.js throws an error saying that it can't find the variable Person. Typescript is supposed to catch runtime failures like this at compile time.

Comment: Well, if you choose to use global classes instead of properly using modules, you are shooting yourself in the foot. TypeScript must support global classes, because they exist in JS. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to use them.

Comment: Similar code would also throw an error in node.js because it doesn't have a concept of global classes. So I'm wondering if there's a compiler option in typescript which forbids global classes.

Comment: I though about the `module` compiler option, but the default is `CommonJS` i.e. adapted for NodeJs! Perhaps with the value `ES6` but it will change your modules syntax (e.g. from `required()` to `import ...`)

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal it looks like a compiler option is being debated: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14306